# include statement works in spec, not in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, asset-pipeline

I have a module stored in `root/vendor/app_name/lib/qa.rb` and a rake task in `root/vendor/app_name/lib/qa.rake`

This is the top of `qa.rb`

```
module QA
  include Module1, Module2

  ...

end
```

And the top of my rake task has `require 'qa'`

Module2 and Module1 are both stored in `root/vendor/app_name/app/models/module_name`

When I run my test, which is stored in `root/spec/app_name/unit/qa/qa_spec.rb`, the tests pass.

When I run the rake task that calls the method in qa.rb, I get the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant QA::Module1
/root/vendor/app_name/lib/qa.rb:2:in `<module:QA>'
/root/vendor/app_name/lib/qa.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/root/vendor/app_name/lib/tasks/qa.rake:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/root/vendor/app_name/lib/tasks/qa.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/zeus-0.15.3/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:50:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/zeus-0.15.3/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:50:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/zeus-0.15.3/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:43:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:383:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:383:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:449:in `load_tasks'
/vagrant/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
```

Why am I getting this error here but not in my test?

Comment: try `include ::Module1, ::Module2`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko no luck, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to describe rake task as

```
task qa: :environment do
  ...
end
```

That will tell rake to load application environment